# Embed html in C# Forms

Tags: c#, html, winforms

Is there a way to embed HTML into a windows forms custom usercontrol? I want to create a lightweight control to be used in a .NET 4.0 application, but since the contents of it is viable to change, I was thinking using HTML to lay it out might be easiest. Is there a way to achieve this in windows forms? There are some other topics with C# and HTML but pretty sure non involves creating a control that parses HTML and displays it.

Thanks

Comment: communicating with a webbrowser control in a winform app is a PITA, I'd avoid choosing HTML just because you want the layout to be changable, its going to be far easier to dynamic load controls (on the fly) at runtime depending on config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `WebBrowser`, but I'd recommend not going down that path. Just use traditional controls to accomplish what you need, if at all possible, maybe combined with a little GDI+.

Comment: WebBrowser is ... finicky. I second the "not .. that path". WPF is sort of "HTML-like" and relatively easy to embed with WinForms. (With the downside (?) it still uses the WPF stack.)

Comment: Unfortunately this is strictly a WinForms app. I mean I could parse the HTML myself and use GDI or D2D or whatever to render the elements, but I was wondering if there is something out of the box that parses HTML and renders it that is available, since I want to avoid writing a whole DOM parser from scratch...

Comment: Like I said, `WebBrowser`. That's a standard Windows Forms control. But otherwise - no, or at least, not until I come out with BreezeCSS. What is it that's so complicated that it merits markup?

Comment: It's like Jeremy mentioned above; I am looking for something that I can quickly revamp the layout for, and something I can come up with quickly. Dynamically loading controls at runtime based on config (mentioned above) or parsing HTML and rendering myself are both doable, but will take some time...

What are the issues with using WebBrowser?

Comment: And this layout can't be done with the standard controls? `FlowLayoutPanel` might be worth checking out, but without more specifics, I can't be... specific.

Comment: As for the issues with `WebBrowser` - slow, not elegant, uses the IE 8 rendering engine (which is lacking in features), and not portable.

Comment: They can be done with standard controls, but they are not easily adjustable/re-layout-able (if that's a word) without having a somewhat decent system in place. I will try out WebBrowser as a quick dirty first pass and re-evaluate down the road for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

A WebBrowser would be your best bet in terms of ease of use and maintenance. You can have further control over the contents themselves by accessing the browser.Document.DomDocument interfaces and events. I would not recommend using GDI since it can become a pain to maintain and manage custom rendering in the long run.

Comment: I agree GDI is over the top but using a webbrowser control is to display webpages, too much business logic ends up is in the presentation tier if you use them as a usercontrols - maze well just make a web app then

Comment: @JeremyThompson: Agreed. However, with most questions on SO, you cannot guage the size of project being discussed and the op's limitations. I myself sometimes resort to a web browser control where quick formatted content is required. Some projects are just not worth best practices. In others, I could be shot for saying that.

Comment: Thanks for the responses/tips. As mentioned in above post, time is the main bottleneck atm. I will try out WebBrowser as a quick dirty first pass and re-evaluate down the road for a better/cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to do a similar thing and have found [awesomium](http://www.awesomium.com).  They have a dotnet and mono wrapper and quite fine grain control over the whole thing acts.  It is also free as long as your company makes less than 100k a year.

Forgot to mention it is a browser that you basically embed in your application so you don't need to worry about the user not having it installed or anything and is consistant over pc's and OS's