# Using other languages inside of C#?

Tags: c#, css, .net, winforms

I am looking for someone who knows the language C# pretty well and can help me answer this question that I have been looking for an answer for all day, google searches result in nothing really "new" and its usually from years ago.

I'm looking for a way that I can use languages like CSS and HTML in WinForms applications? I know WPF has a better, more cleaner UI look than WinForms but still, its very ugly and definitely not modern.

Is there a way I can use CSS or some sort of framework that enhances the styling a lot in C# WinForms? The UI controls right now are very ugly.

I'm looking to create nice, clean looking applications like Skype, Spotify, and Visual Studio, and more. Is there any pre-made frameworks or packages to help with this?

Or any idea that anyone can give...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embed html in C# Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343974/embed-html-in-c-sharp-forms)

Comment: That's about embedding HTML using a web browser, I am asking how to make the core controls of the .NET framework more appealing, this is taking the question totally out of topic.

Comment: I have already specified that this is for WinForms. I'm actually not sure why the moderator has added the wpf tag as I have made it clear I'm not using wpf.

Comment: This should help you :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184856/how-good-can-winforms-make-a-ui-look-using-free-resources-only

Comment: Frankly, claiming that Winforms or WPF are "very ugly and definitely not modern" is a variation on the old saying, "a poor carpenter blames his tools". You can make a Winforms or WPF program look like whatever you want. WPF especially makes this easy, but even in Winforms, you're not limited to the default appearance for anything. At the same time, there's **nothing** about CSS and HTML that inherently makes things look good. As anyone who was around when the web first showed up would tell you.

Answer (score 1):

HTML is a markup language and together with CSS they are used for styling webpages and are designed for displaying text, images, etc. on the web.

They do not provide an interactive experience or event driven approach which is required for windows applications.   Javascript is mainly used to enhance the web pages to allow a more interactive approach, but this is still not to the level that is possible in winforms.  Although modern approaches such as Angular2, Node.js etc. allow you to do much more.

So if you want to use these technologies then the link provide by John Wu ([Embed html in C# Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343974/embed-html-in-c-sharp-forms)) is the right approach.

However, the all applications running on the windows desktop applications use the basic windows Winforms or WPF underneath they are just heavily customised so with the right amount of effort then it is possible for you to achieve the same look and feel as they have but also using winforms or WPF.

You can program this yourself using themes, or there are even some tools out there which will help you to apply different styles to your applications.  I think that this blog actually gives a nice summary to several options:

http://blogs.artinsoft.net/Mrojas/archive/2012/04/27/Customizing-the-Look-and-Feel-or-your-Windows-Forms-Applications.aspx